# is it possible to create woocommerce website in wordpress without pro theme?

Tags: wordpress

is it possible to create woo-commerce website in WordPress without pro theme? I do not want customize theme and want to create website about EV Bazar.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Loads of free themes that do include a woocommerce support. Have a look at some here https://wordpress.org/themes/tags/e-commerce/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.